# Is there a way to store a datetime variable in ISO format in Cosmos db while I'm using C# with mongo drivers

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm trying to store timestamp in one of my collections. With all the attributes associated to BsonDateTimeOptions, I'm still  finding this in my cosmosdb.

```
"TimeStamp" : {
        "$date" : 1616491438917
    },
```

While I'm actually looking for

```
"TimeStamp" : "yyyy-MM-ddTHH\\:mm\\:ss.fffffffzzz",
```

Comment: Why do you want to store it in ISO format? If you want to retain the time offset, you should use a `DateTimeOffset` in C#, otherwise use a `DateTime`. If you want to actually save it as a string in the database then you should treat it as a `string` in C#.

Comment: `"$date" : 1616491438917` is equal to `ISODate("2021-03-23T09:23:58.917Z")` - it's just the way how your client displays it. Usually you should be able to set in your client preferences how date values are displayed. Or use [BsonDateTime.ToUniversalTime](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.6/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Bson_BsonDateTime_ToUniversalTime.htm)

Comment: Thank you very much. This would be really helpful.